# Packaging Project errors: 'Conflicting values for resource' and 'Duplicate Entry'

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, win-universal-app, .net-standard

I'm trying to package my UWP app with desktop extensions and was told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50023638/939213)  that it's impossible to do that without a Packaging Project. But when I add a Packaging Project, and set it to the UWP project and the Win32 project, I get the following errors. Note that this is all that Visual Studio is giving me. No line numbers, etc.

> Error PRI277  0xdef00532 - Conflicting values for resource
>   ''    myFolderPath\UwpPackager\GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE 1

(That's not a double quote. It's 2 quotes.)

And

> Error     Duplicate Entry.    myFolderPath\UwpPackager\error PRI175   1

What do these errors mean?

Comment: Hi @ispiro. Can you share the complete log files? (running msbuild /v:diag ) and/or detailed repro steps? (you can find me in rmpablos at ms dot com).

Comment: @rido Thanks. After much testing it turned out to be the 'Assets' folder that was automatically created withing the packaging project. I excluded the folder and that error is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much testing it turned out to be the 'Assets' folder that was automatically created withing the packaging project.

I excluded the folder and that error is gone.

**EDIT**

According to a comment elsewhere I need to have the assets in the packaging project because that's what's going to be published.