# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

I'm working with VS 2019, version 16.9.1 using .NET framework.
I ran my code today after it works fine yesterday, but today I received this exception:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

It occurs when I'm creating a new class(that I wrote)

I tried these solutions:

1. Add System.Private.CoreLib.dll as a reference but it didn't help(I guess it's for .NET core)
2. Change to an older version of my .NET framework (right now is 4.72.2) but it didn't help as well.
3. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010855/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-private-corelib), but it's a different case.

Any help will be appreciated

Thank

Comment: Maybe you can submit an issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues).

Comment: I'll check it out. Thanks